# automatically print last created file in a folder

Tags: printing

Every day at a specific time 4 different XLS files are created in 4 different folders, where is stored all history with hundreds of files

I want to automatically print the latest created file, but how can I create a `.bat` (or anything else) to print only the latest XLS without printing all the others?

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "c:\prova*.*" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I 
  lpr -S ITKPOMPRNTCTR02 -P raw %NewestFile%
```

with this, I find the latest file in the folder and it is working

but the error I get is (copied from the command prompt exit screen)

```
lpr -S ITKPOMPRNTCTR02 -P raw pppp.xls
```

> Error: could not open pppp.xls for reading

I tried also with TXT files (hoping that XLS  file could be the problem) but no luck, same error

the printer I need to use is a network printer, I tried putting after `-S`

- `//PrintServer/PrinterName`
- `//PrintServerIP/PrinterName` or `PrinterIP`

nothing works

I even tried with:

```
net use lpt1: \\printerserver\printname
print %NewestFile% /c /d:lpt1
```

but I receive:

> system error 66 the network resource type is not correct

Please note, that I'm launching from domain user this script.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. I tried this script --------------- FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "c:\prova\*.*" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
lpr -S ITKPOMPRNTCTR02 -P raw %NewestFile% ---------------- but the result was ------ lpr -S ITKPOMPRNTCTR02 -P raw pppp.txt
Error: could not open pppp.txt for reading.

Comment: this is a try, then I want to print xls files using LibreOffice calc

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code there, using proper code formatting.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/982384/yordan) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/982957/yordan). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You seem to have many problems.  (1) How to find the newest file in a directory.  (2) How to find the newest ***xls*** file in a directory (even if there’s a `.txt` file that’s newer).  (3) How to print an xls file from the command line.  (4) How to print an xls file from a batch file.  (5) How to format code in Super User. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … You seem to have a good handle on #1, but help us help you.  When you ran the command you say you ran, what was the newest file in the directory?  Was it `pppp.txt`?  Was it `pppp.xls`?  *Is* there a ```pppp.xls``` file?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Skipping ahead to #5 — are you really typing `FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "c:\prova*.*" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I lpr -S ITKPOMPRNTCTR02 –P raw %NewestFile%` as one line?  If not, please [edit] your question and insert line break(s) in the appropriate places.  (Ditto for the error message.) … … … … … … … … … … Skipping back to #3, can you successfully print an xls file (whose name you know) from the command line?  Please [edit] your question and show us the command you use.